# python email get values for multiple headers of the same name

Tags: python, parsing, email

I'm using python's `email.message_from_string` to parse a raw email message. However, the message has multiple "Recieved" headers in it. When I call `message.keys()` their are clearly several Recieved headers. But when I try message.get("Recieved") I just get `""` a null string. How do you get the values of those instances of that header?

Comment: I don't suppose its a spelling error is it? (i.e. Recieved should be received).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `get_all(name[, failobj])`
>
> Return a list of all the values for the field named name. If there are no such named headers in the message, failobj is returned (defaults to None).

Source: http://docs.python.org/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.get_all